# java android getResources().getIdentifier() of elment at alertdialog with LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, identifier

I try to get dynamically an identifier of some checkbox in a AlertDialog.
But I do not find the right code for this.
Every time I get return 0.

I have a test to get id of alert title `("android:id/alertTitle")`
And this works fine. But I'am not able to reach my inflater-ID's
For me it seems like the context is wrong?

```py
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Claim.this);
        builder.setView(optionmenu);

        final CheckBox[] myCheckBox = new CheckBox[checkedItems.length];
        builder.setTitle("Select pages for claim");
        builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        for(int i=0; i<checkedItems.length; i++) {
            String checkboxID = "android:id/optionspage"+i+"CheckBox";
            int resID = builder.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(checkboxID, null,  null);
            myCheckBox[i] = ((CheckBox) findViewById(resID));
            myCheckBox[i].setChecked(checkedItems[i]);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: what is your final goal

Comment: I want to dynamic creat a list of checkboxes and asign a value to each.
And if i press positive button i will save the actuel state of the boxes back to my used value.

So i think that is a clean solutuin and worked perfekt for me.
Would be great to know if there is a way to .setChecked with .getResources in a AlertDialog with custom view.
After i try to generate the boxes automaticly i figgert out i can du it by a other way. There i can add a setOnCheckedChangeListener to each box and get value.